# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. when accessing firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I successfully register a new user into firebase but can't create the user's document in firestore.
I get the following error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (18812): Receiver: null
E/flutter (18812): Tried calling: []("uid")
E/flutter (18812): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter (18812): #1      new UserModel.fromMap (package:hil_app/models/user_model.dart:17:16)
E/flutter (18812): #2      AuthController.streamFirestoreUser.<anonymous closure> (package:hil_app/controllers/auth_controller.dart:66:40)
```

Here is my controller class

```
  Stream<UserModel> streamFirestoreUser() {
    if (firebaseUser?.value?.uid != null) {
      return _db
          .doc('/users/${firebaseUser.value.uid}')
          .snapshots()
          .map((snapshot) => UserModel.fromMap(snapshot.data()));
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Here is my User Model

```
    return UserModel(
      uid: data['uid'],
      name: data['name'] ?? '',
      email: data['email'] ?? '',
      password: data['password'] ?? '',
      dob: data['dob'] ?? '',
      gender: data['gender'] ?? '',
      phone: data['phone'] ?? '',
      agree: data['accept_terms'] ?? '',
      photoUrl: data['photoUrl'] ?? '',
    );
  }
```

any idea on how to solve this error?

Comment: Your `data` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the document doesn't exist, so the `data()` call in this then fails:

```
UserModel.fromMap(snapshot.data())
```

One simple way to fix this problem is to pass an empty map when the snapshot doesn't exist:

```
UserModel.fromMap(snapshot.exists ? snapshot.data() : {})
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find out where the error was coming from

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because your data is null try to replace

```
UserModel.fromMap(snapshot.data()));
```

with

```
UserModel.fromMap(snapshot.data));
```